# GitHub error "Failed to get HEAD"

Tags: macos, github

I'm new to GitHub and mainly going to be using it to backup service and to show off code. Anyhow, I'm trying to get my latest program up there and am getting the error in the title of this thread when I try to push.

Repro steps:

- Sit in Starbucks with crappy wifi (Could this be related to the problem? Serious question.)
- Open latest version of GitHub for latest Macintosh operating system
- File --> New Repository
- Local Path --> the folder that contains my XCode project
- Name --> give it a name
- Publish
- Sync
- Push .... Get error
- Look in my XCode project's folder and it looks like an empty subfolder with the name of my GitHub project was created there. Huh?

Answer (score 5):

I had these issues, I followed these steps to resolve.

```
cd /directory

git init

git add .

git commit -m "Name of Repo"
```

I then opened the github desktop application and dragged the folder over. 
All my files are now available and I can make commits. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I received a similar error using GitHub Desktop on OS X. I got the error when trying to commit files for the first time to a newly created repository. The error message was something along the following: Failed To Get Head (Unborn)

The steps I followed to create the error were:

1. Created a new repository on GitHub.com
2. Cloned the empty repository using GitHub Desktop
3. Created a new project locally on my computer inside the directory I cloned the repository to in step 2.
4. Using GitHub Desktop, tried to commit the files. This is when I got the error.

To "fix" this, I went to GitHub desktop and created a ReadMe for the repository. I then 'Synced' the repository on GitHub Desktop and was able to commit.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Synced'?

Answer (score 1):

This error can appear if you did not initiate the repository. make sure to check the box saying "Initialize this repository with a README"

Answer (score 1):

In my case all I needed to do was to run:

```
git add -A
```

After this I was successfully able to commit through the GitHub client.

I was using Xcode and I copied some files into the folder with my project and they were not automatically added to the git (hence the error).

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset
```

And then come back to GitHub Desktop. That works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the Starbucks Wifi.

This happened to me with the official GitHub client when I tried to make an initial commit, I then tried again using the inbuilt versioning module within my code editor (Intellij IDEA) and it worked just fine.

I won't even hazard a guess to the cause of the problem, but try a different GIT client if you need a potential quick fix.

Comment: Funny, this failed for me in Starbucks shitty wi-fi, too!  Starbucks wi-fi now apparently blocks port 22 so I wonder if this had something to do with it.  FWIW, I just used command-line git (`git commit -a -m "Initial commit."` followed by `git push`), and after that the OS X GitHub client worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to commit first and try to push. I am also very new to git, I used to SVN a lot, It worked for me after initial commit.